# fscanf comma seperated in C90

Tags: c, scanf, c89

Hi I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct person {
  int id;
  char firstName[20];
  char lastName[20];
  int year;
  int month;
  int day;
  int friends[100];
};
```

and a txt file that needs to be parsed:

```
Blake,Smith, 1963,12,2
Jake,Doe,1994,3,30
```

and I want it to parse with fscanf:

```
people[i].id = i + 1;
fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%d,%d\n", people[i].firstName, people[i].lastName, &people[i].year, &people[i].month, &people[i].day);
i++;
```

But it stores the whole line into firstname

even when i try to replace ',' with '%*c' it gets even worse and stores 2 lines in firstname

Comment: Don't. Read whole lines via fgets, then parse. It will e.g. allow to understand lines starting with Charles Emerson-Winchester, 3rd.

Comment: Try `%[^,],%[^,],%d,%d,%d\n` as your format specifier string in `fscanf`.

Comment: Worked thx alot